# imports custom module python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror

I have a file `I.py` and `X.py` both are custom modules

I'm trying to do an `import` from `X.py` file like:

```
from myapp.I import Int
```

But, when I try to run in shell, it throws an import error of:

```
ImportError: No module named myapp.I
```

**X.py** is in a subdir of `I.py`

```
X.py is in: myapp/a/x.py
I.py is in: myapp/
```

what am I doing wrong? Sorry this is slightly basic, it seems so trivial, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us your directory structure?

Comment: Added above in a comment

Comment: from myapp.a.x import I

Comment: Im trying to import from within X.py, not I.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need an `__init__.py` within myapp/ and myapp/a/. See [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) for more details.

Comment: If am inheriting I.py into X.py, doesn't this come too?

Comment: Without `__init__.py`, import operations won't be able to recognize a directory in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute `X.py` directly, even with the required `__init__.py` files (have you added those?)

This is a limitation (or feature, depending on how you see it). To get around it, you need to create a simple *runner* script of sorts in the top-level directory which then imports `X` and executes it.